# Implementing Photoshop filters in C#

Tags: c#, .net, image, bitmap, photoshop

I know how to implement them, but what I don't know is whether to apply the transformation pixel by pixel or is there another way to affect the whole image, using a single call, etc?

AFAIK Get.Set Pixel is very slow. I am not sure if they did it this way.

So if it's the grayscale/desaturate filter as a simple case, how would one write it?

Comment: If you know how to implement them, I'd like to see you ask "How do i implement Photoshop filters in C#" and answer it yourself with examples, mostly because I'd love to know how :)

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/GDI-plus/Image_Processing_Lab.aspx or http://www.codeproject.com/KB/GDI-plus/csharpgraphicfilters11.aspx

Comment: @JoanVenge Have you also implemented puppet filter of photoshop? if yes please tell me how to do it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to lock the image and then work with the memory, directly bypassing SetPixel method.
[See here](http://www.vcskicks.com/fast-image-processing.html) or even better [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20141229164101/http://bobpowell.net/lockingbits.aspx).

For examle you can set the blue channel to 255 as follows:

```
   BitmapData bmd=bm.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, 10, 10), System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageLockMode.ReadOnly, bm.PixelFormat);
      int PixelSize=4;
      for(int y=0; y<bmd.Height; y++)
      {
        byte* row=(byte *)bmd.Scan0+(y*bmd.Stride);
        for(int x=0; x<bmd.Width; x++)
        {
          row[x*PixelSize]=255;
        }
      } // it is copied from the last provided link.
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know locking. What does lock does exactly? The link doesn't seem to go into detail with the description. Maybe the method name isn't very descriptive?

Comment: It locks the memory to a physical location so that the .Net memory manager can't move it around during garbage collection.  Yes this uses unsafe code and requires an appropriate unsafe{} section or compiler option.

Comment: @Joan: using LockBits does require the unsafe keyword. This isn't normally a concern at all, but some Windows users can be running under security policies that prohibit unsafe code, so your app wouldn't work. I've never encountered this problem myself, but the threat of it has led me away from using Bitmaps at all. :(

Answer (score 1):

In order to achieve an even faster performance, you may want to check out WPF's Pixel Shader Effects implementation, that works with all .NET WPF visual objects, not just images.

Take a look at an article explaining some basic implementation steps for such an effect:

http://bursjootech.blogspot.com/2008/06/grayscale-effect-pixel-shader-effect-in.html

Comment: Thanks, that's a good example. Out of curiosity, do you know if all PS effects are possible with pixel shaders? I am not too familiar with pixel shaders but AFAIK it's only for the simplest effects, like color shifting, grayscale, etc.

Comment: @Joan Venge Now, with WPF 4, PS 3.0 effects can be implemented and this makes it possible to write very complex ones. Check out the Shazzam Pixel Shader Utility at http://shazzam-tool.com/default.html download the latest version and see for yourself the kind of effects that you can write.